# How to load the specific node from XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I want to get a load from following XML

```
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
  <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
    <Assertion ID="_a2baec61-1e5a-4f7e-8cc4-44ca3cb82a44" IssueInstant="2012-10-30T11:56:19.211Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
      <Issuer>https://vidizmo1-ac.accesscontrol.windows.net/</Issuer>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
          <ds:Reference URI="#_a2baec61-1e5a-4f7e-8cc4-44ca3cb82a44">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>XsW696+Y/CkArU5a8zvqeEckl+rpgiv0lEEs2PDx3Hw=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>

      </ds:Signature>

      **<AttributeStatement>
        <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
          <AttributeValue>farooqtest11@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
          </Attribute>
          <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
            <AttributeValue>farooq test</AttributeValue>
          </Attribute>
          <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider">
            <AttributeValue>Google</AttributeValue>
          </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>**

    </Assertion>
  </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
  <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
  <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
  <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
</t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

and my code is :

```
  string xml = @"C:\Users\baseer.haider\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CheckReadXML\CheckReadXML\ACS.xml";
            XmlDocument acsXml = new XmlDocument();
            acsXml.Load(xml);
            XmlNodeList acsNode = acsXml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//AttributeStatement//Attribute");

            foreach (XmlNode node in acsNode)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["Name"] != null)
                {
                    if (node.Attributes["Name"].Value == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")
                    {
                        var innerNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//AttributeValue");
                        Console.WriteLine(innerNode.InnerText);
                    }

                }
```

I want to load  node from the following XML but I cant load it because when I select that node using this code
XmlNodeList acsNode = `acsXml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//AttributeStatement//Attribute");`

acsNode is Empty.
can any body fix this plz??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LINQ2XML**

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("yourStream.xml");
XNamespace t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust";
XNamespace a="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion";

var lstElmVal=doc.Descendants(t+"RequestedSecurityToken")
.Descendants(t+"Assertion")
.Element(a+"AttributeStatement")
.Elements(a+"Attribute")
.Where(x=>x.Attribute("Name").Value=="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")
.Select(y=>y.Value);

//lstElmVal now contains your required data
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq2Xml is much more easier.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XNamespace ns = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion";

var attvals = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "AttributeValue")
                  .Select(x => x.Value)
                  .ToList();
```